# How to mock StreamingOutput from jax-rs

Tags: java, mockito, jax-rs

I have a class which send video as mp4 file to user (Http request/response)
I want to Mock method with main logic to test it. My code

```
public StreamingOutput videoAsStream(final String videoUrl) {
        try {
            final URL url = new URL(videoUrl);
            return output -> {
                try(final InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream()){
                    IOUtils.copy(inputStream,output);
                    output.close();
                }
            };
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            log.error("Url exception for url {}",videoUrl);
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
```

What is my way to mock this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that URL is final, so you will have to use at least Mockito 2 to mock it. If you are ready to do that, I see two possibilities:

a) Give the url into the method and not the string, thus allowing you to put a mocked url in there. That would be the most simply method. You could also then create a 2nd convenience method that creates said URL from a string. Those two methods will be easier to test because their scope is smaller.

b) Extract the `final URL url = new URL(videoUrl);` part into a new class, for example a URL Factory, then mock that to return a mocked URL object in your test.

As soon as you produce stuff with "new" inside your method, this method can become harder to test, because you now cannot separate this test from this object generation.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't mock `final` and `static` methods/classes using `mockito`. you would have to depend on `PowerMockito`. I am currently not able to test your method but if you want to mock final/static, you can do as 
first, Add the final/static classes to `@PrepareForTest` then

```
InputStream mockInputStream = Mockito.mock(InputStream.class);
OutputStream mockOutputStream = Mockito.mock(OutputStream.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(IOUtils.class);
Mockito.when(IOUtils.copy(mockInputStream, mockOutputStream)).thenReturn(1L);
Mockito.doNothing().when(mockOutputStream).close();
```

Let me know if this does not work for you.

Comment: Actually, Mockito 2 offers a way to mock final methods and classes. But that's beside the point. Having to resort to use PowerMockito for your own code is a sign that said code is bad.